# How to send a message directly if Outlook is only temporarily active for "mailto:" links?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, mailto

Is there any way to configure Outlook to send messages without Outlook being open?

We're currently using a system where the "Email Page" opens an Outlook Sendto window. You can click "Send", but the message stays in the "Outbox" until you open Outlook. I'm trying to get around opening Outlook. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can configure the Options for Outlook to Send/Receive at certain time intervals.  I would say, make this 1 minute, and then this problem you see would be remedied each minute, if items are in your outbox.

[image]

Comment: That would solve the problem if I wanted to keep Outlook open. I'm trying to get Outlook to send the message without it being open.

Comment: As far as I know this operation is initiated without Outlook being open.  See picture attached to my answer.

Comment: The "Perform an automatic send/receive when exiting" seems promising too. I guess Outlook *is* active even when it's only fired up to send a single message, so if it then closes automatically that might count as "exiting" as well?

Comment: The send/receive when existing actually is send/receive before exiting.  The send/receive offline occurs when the Outlook GUI is offline and the process kicks on behind the scenes.

Comment: I think I figured out the issue. The version I am using (200) is opening Word to write the Email. The new version of outlook actually opens Outlook. Looks like I'll have to do a little more digging.